# Bootstrap tooltip stuck on span click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/) datepicker for a booking system. I need a tooltip when hovering over the dates as you can see in the code below. Since I am using the plugin as a range picker, when I click on a date to select the start of the range and and I hover to another date, the tooltip remains stuck on the date I clicked.

If I don't select any dates and hover over the dates, the `mouseleave` works just fine. The solutions I came across suggested adding `trigger: 'hover'` but this is not solving my problem.

Each cell of the datepicker is a span which contains the class `.flatpickr-day`.

```
$('.flatpickr-day').on({
    'mouseover': function() {
        let date = moment(new Date($(this).attr('aria-label'))).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

        if (date in finalPriceObj) {
            $(this)
                .tooltip({
                    container: 'body',
                    html: true,
                    trigger: 'hover',
                    placement: 'bottom',
                    title: function() {
                        let priceObj   = finalPriceObj[date],
                            text       = 'oldRate' in priceObj ? '<del>Rs . '+ priceObj['oldRate'] +'</del>&nbsp;Rs. ' + priceObj['newRate'] : 'Rs. ' + priceObj['newRate'],
                            startRange = $('.startRange');

                        if (startRange.length > 0) {
                            console.log(startRange);
                        }


                        return text;
                    }
                })
                .tooltip('show');
        }
    },
    'mouseleave': function() {
        $(this).tooltip('hide');
    }
});
```

In this case, the tooltip should have been appearing below cell `27`.

[image]

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jolan123456789/Lfd986hy/) of the issue.

Comment: Hi, can you make this runnable ?

Comment: @Swati hello, I updated the post with a jsfiddle link

Comment: I tried adding `$(this).tooltip('hide');` in a `click` function; it hides the tooltip on click, but the mouseover doesn't work again after that.

Comment: Yes i tested that i am trying to do this some other way but , i think flatpicker is messing with tooltip because it has its own mouseover events .. Will let you know if i found any solution.

Comment: Did you resolve this ?

Comment: @Swati unfortunately no, I am going to use jquery ui's datepicker instead.